# How to run a shell script while compiling a recipe in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have created a bash shell script, and want this script to be executed while I build that recipe(under which script was created). So I want bitbake to run this script while building recipe. What should I add into .bb file?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: depends on what your skript shall do. But generally just create a task or easier, make a do_compile_append(){ ${WORKDIR}/<your-script> <arguments>} and it will be run. If there is no do_compile task yet, you can omit _append or just use another task

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a script in a recipe you can define a task and add a dependency to it

This is in my `uboot.bb` file. With this the uboot image is copied to a directory every time uboot is compiled

The `before do_build` means that this script is executed every time you run `bitbake <recipe>`

The `after do deploy` means that every time uboot is compiled this script is executed.

```sh
PACKET_OUTDIR ?= "${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/out"
UBOOT_OUTFILE ?= "${MACHINE}.uboot"

# Copy bin after compile
addtask bin after do_deploy before do_build
# redo task if vardeps variables changed from last execution
do_bin[vardeps] = "UBOOT_OUTFILE PACKET_OUTDIR"
do_bin() {
  # create directory
  install -d ${PACKET_OUTDIR}
  
  # copy uboot bin to the out directory and print output on display  
  bbplain $(cp -vH ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${UBOOT_MAKE_TARGET}-${UBOOT_CONFIG} ${PACKET_OUTDIR}/${UBOOT_OUTFILE})  
  
  # run an external script in home
  ~/external_script.sh
}
```

If you want to run the script before the compiling just use `before do_compile`